# Orbeon Upgrade to 2017.2 throwing errors on form edit

Tags: orbeon

We are trying to upgrade from Orbeon 2016.2 to 2017.2 and getting below error while calling form edit.

```
|`oxf.xforms.state.manager.uuid-list-key` was not set in the session. Check your listeners.                            |
```

Cannot find any information in release notes regarding any entry to make older version forms work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That session key, `oxf.xforms.state.manager.uuid-list-key`, is created when a new session is created. This is done via `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Could it be that you don't have the Orbeon Forms 2017.2 `web.xml`?

Comment: Excellent @skariyil, I am glad that was it, and thank you for the update.

Comment: Hi @avernet, now I am getting another error. The form is not displaying and I can see 'xforms-initially-hidden' class for <form>, and removing it by jquery is causing other js errors, means orbeon js is not functioning.. FYI we are using Liferay 6.2 (weblogic). Would you able to help with this?

Comment: Hi @skariyil, the `xforms-initially-hidden` still being there is typically a sign that something went wrong during the JavaScript initialization. I'd first try to see if the problem persists if you load the page in a new Private Window, to see if it is a caching issue. If it still happens there, I'd open the Chrome Dev Tools (or similar), and look for error in the console. You'll let us know what you find!

Comment: Hi @avernet, thanks for the update. In chrome it didn't show any errors in browser inspect. But seeing below in FireFox. But that resource is available if I try to access the resource from browser.

Comment: Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://<url>/smartforms?p_p_id=orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssf_smartforms_portlet_orbeon_proxy_portlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=%2Fxforms-server%2Fc9a0eb66dc430e3ba9fae0205b74cc95ebbc03d2%2Forbeon-11043994106ff3c22ad99fd2ae8af49b1933920d.js&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-3&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4
Source Map URL: form-runner.min.js.map[Learn More]

Comment: OK @skariyil, the browser not being able to load source maps isn't a problem; those are just used for development, and some browsers will try to load them when you open their Dev Tools. However, it seems you're using Liferay, which could be related to the problem; are you using the Proxy Portlet? Are you using Orbeon Forms CE or PE?

Comment: Yes, it's proxy portlet and using PE.

Comment: we are using weblogic 12c, Liferay 6.2 and Orbeon 2017.2

Comment: we have upgraded to 2018.1.3, but still same behavior. But if we roll back to 2016.2 it works fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Got it @skariyil; since you're using Orbeon Forms PE, and you have support with us, and it will be be easier and faster to help you this way. Do you already have access Basecamp? If so, could you post a message there, with a reference to this page on Stack Overflow? If not, can you send us an email to info AT orbeon.com, also referencing this discussions, and we'll set you up!

Comment: Thank you @skariyil for the message on Basecamp; so we'll be in touch there.